# Should we JavaDoc classes extending abstract classes?

Tags: java, javadoc

Suppose I am writing a class "MyWork" extending the abstract class "Work". Now, assume all methods I need in "MyWork" have already been declared and have had their JavaDoc written in "Work". Should I still add the JavaDoc in "MyWork"?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

It depends. If you're not overriding any method, there's no option to add Javadoc (only at class level). It could make sense to add some Javadoc to the class explaining why it exists.

If you're overriding methods, you can write Javadoc like this:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * This implementation also does...
 */
```

Answer (score 2):

For non-public code, I wouldn't bother with anything that `@inheritDoc` doesn't handle.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the methods in `MyWork` override any functionality in `Work`, then it's safe to presume that the methods behave similarly to their superclass.  There shouldn't be any reason to document non-overridden methods or fields.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about abstract Methods, so the "MyWork" Class needs to Override them.

If they don't have any special behavior, you do not need to add a new JavaDoc. Otherwise document how they implement the abstract method.Normally there must be a reason why this method is abstract and must be implemented in the inheriting class and it's not implemented in the abstract class itself.

you can use `{@inheritDoc}` to get the Text of the inherited Doumentation and then add the special behavior below it.